# Include files from different directory in target

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile that compiles an `.so` object. Now, there is a need to compile some `.o`'s in different object, and include them into the large `.so`.
Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
FLAGS=-Wall 
SOURCES=$(shell echo *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
OBJ_FLAGS=-c -fPIC

INCL_DIR=./include
UTILS_DIR=./utils/
INCLUDES=-I/usr/include -I$(INCL_DIR) -I$(UTILS_DIR)

TARGET=ap_pcie_lib.so
TARGET_FLAGS=-shared

all: clean build_utils build_obj build_target cleanup

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o *.so build/
    @sudo rm -f $(LIBPATH)$(TARGET)

build_utils:
    make -C utils/ # I wish to use three .o files from here

build_obj: $(OBJECTS)

build_target: $(TARGET)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -DTIME=$(TIME) $(OBJ_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(TARGET):
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET_FLAGS) -o $(TARGET)
    
cleanup:
    @rm -r *.o
```

So there are three `*.o` files that get created in `.utils/`, but I don't know how to include them in my current `$(TARGET)`? I've tried to do this inside of `$(TARGET)` rule, but it forbids me to change this variable inside of a rule.

```
OBJECTS += $(shell echo utils/*.o)
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are the only .o files there you can just use utils/*.o again.

Answer (score 1):

Add the objects as prerequisites to the TARGETS rule and use the automatic variable `$^` to expand them in the recipe:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(TARGET_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

# expands into something like "gcc -shared -o ap_pcie_lib.so ap_pcie_lib.o utils/a.o utils/b.o utils/c.o"
```